# Proving the closure and boundary of a specific open set

Tags: real-analysis

Let $X$ = $R^2$ with the Euclidean metric and let $S$ = {($x_1$,$x_2$) : $x_1^2$ + $x_2^2$ $\lt$ 1}.
Prove that $\bar{S}$ = {($x_1$,$x_2$) : $x_1^2$ + $x_2^2$ $\le$ 1} and that $∂S$ = {($x_1$,$x_2$) : $x_1^2$ + $x_2^2$ = 1}.

Intuitively, I understand that the closure of S would just be the closed circle with radius 1 and all of its interior points and that the boundary of S would just be the same closed circle but without the interior points. But I am struggling on how I actually prove this.

Any nudge in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closure is the set union its limit points.  So take a point in the limit set.   By definition, any neighborhood of that point has a point in S in it,  so for any epsilon, via the triangle inequality,  you get the distance from that point is less than or equal to 1 + any epsilon.  Since this works for any epsilon, the distance to the point is less than or equal to 1.   Now take a point in the closed circle, and show it's either in S or a limit point (Easy).

The boundary is the closure minus the interior....the interior is the inner ball, the closure is the solid disk, so the boundary is the circle

Answer (score 0):

Definition: $\bar S = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^2 : $ some sequence in $S$ converges to $x\}$.

Every point in $S$ is in the closure $\bar S$, because the constant sequence at each point converges to that point. All the points x on the outer circle are in the closure because the sequence $\frac{n}{n+1}x$ is contained in $S$ and converges to $x$.

Every other point has an $\epsilon$ ball around it with no elements of $S$ in it, so it is not in the closure.

$\partial S = \bar S \backslash int(S) = $ circle.